# Add user if entered user isn't inside listed from autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have an autocomplete that read mysql out * of customersName.
On keyup or onchange, doesn't matter which one, so, if user do not exist in mysql I need to display an new input (hidden) and submit button to add new customer by name and email.

I need to know in which direction to search, I didn't find any info.

Js:

```
$(function() {
    if ($('body').is('.PageType')) {
        $("#klantnaam").autocomplete({
            source: "zoekklant.php",
            minLength: 0,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#klantnaam").val(ui.item.value);
                var str = ui.item.id;
                document.getElementById('doekprijs').textContent = str + " \u20ac";
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: *"if user do not exist in mysql i need to display an new input (hided) and submit button to add new customer by name and email."* Sounds like a **race condition** about to happen.. You should also add a UNIQUE key in your table to prevent duplications

Comment: You will need to look in the direction of Ajax (XMLHTTPRequest) so you can ask a PHP page to query the table data and give you a JSON response? And based on that JSON response you show the form field and submit button with JQuery.

Comment: Yes Raymond , I have UNIQUE key